# Not able to retrieve Form variables by processDefinitionId

Tags: java, workflow, bpmn, camunda

I'm using camunda jars and working on an experimental case to build custom forms for the processes. I read the docs and learnt that form variables can be fetched from form service `getStartFormVariables` method. consider the below code:

```
String processDefinitionId = "generatedFormsQuickstart:1:2503";
Gson gson = new Gson();
String result = gson.toJson(processEngine.getFormService().getStartFormVariables(processDefinitionId));
System.out.println(result);
result = gson.toJson(processEngine.getFormService().getRenderedStartForm(processDefinitionId));
System.out.println(result);
```

Here in result the first sysout prints `{}` whereas the second prints the whole form `"\u003cform name\u003d\"generatedFo...` with all variables.

I'm confused of why variables are not being retrieved but the built forms are retrieved.

Comment: Although I'm starting to get involved with Camunda, I don't know enough to answer this question, but I would point out that the source is available.  If you can run your application in Eclipse, then execute it in the debugger and step into the method and see if you can find a clue why "getStartFormVariables" returns what it does.

Comment: For someone interested in solution can go through this link here https://forum.camunda.org/t/not-able-to-retrieve-form-variables-via-getstartformvariables-by-processdefinitionid/3050/9